# Want to use right mouse button for caps typing with on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

The on-screen keyboard for Windows 7/8 requires use of the CAPS keys for caps control.  Is there a way to right-click on a letter key for it to toggle to the other case from using a left-click?

For instance, I would like to type with the on-screen keyboard using single clicks of the right mouse button to select the key case. Having to select CAPS or CAPS lock with the left mouse button first adds extra clicks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the on-screen keyboard that comes with windows 7. There are programs you can download that will have this capability. Just google for it.

Comment: I have already done basic searches for this but to no avail.  Most searches discuss using the on-screen keyboard to accomplish mouse functions.  My goal is to use the mouse right-click (or center click) function for upper case letters and the left click for lower case letters.

Comment: @PScott then how come one search leads me to this? http://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/help-online/ explaining that their software does this?